# msbuild deploy command fails with exception

Tags: sql-server, msbuild

I'm trying to deploy sql server database thought CMD with msbuild (it works fine from VS).
This is the command I'm using:

```
msbuild "Database Services\Database Services.sqlproj" /t:deploy /p:TargetConnectionString="TEST05,123;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False" /p:TargetDatabase="test_fsdb"
```

but I'm getting the below exception:

```
error MSB4018: The "SqlDeployTask" task failed unexpectedly. [C:\project\Database Services\Database Services.sqlproj]
error MSB4018: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'TEST05,123;integrated security'. [C:\project\Database Services\Database Services.sqlproj]]
```

What does this error means? I don't understand which argument causing the issue

Comment: Have you tried starting the TargetConnectionString with `Server=`?

Comment: problem solved. I will post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Data Source was missing from the TargetConnectionString:

```
TargetConnectionString="Data Source=TEST05,123;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"
```